# Is $\mathbb{R}P^1 \times \mathbb{R}P^1 = \mathbb{R}P^2$? If it isn't what does it look like?

Tags: general-topology, projective-space

We know that $\mathbb{R}P^1$ may be conceptualized as the set of all lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Alternatively, it may be conceptualized as a hemisphere of $S^1$ with antipodal points at the equator identified. How to think of $\mathbb{R}P^1 \times \mathbb{R}P^1$?

Answer (score 7):

No. $\Bbb RP^1$ is homeomorphic to a circle, which makes $\Bbb RP^1\times \Bbb RP^1$ into a torus, which is definitely not homeomorphic to $\Bbb RP^2$

Comment: So $T^1$, $S^1$, and $\mathbb{R}P^1$ are all just... $S^1$?

Comment: @Johnver Yes, they are.